# How to return a dataset from handler?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

like from a class we return a dataset like this.. values get from a database and bind in grid view or any thing else.

```
public DataSet GetImgPath()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectImg", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            return ds;
        }
        catch
        {
            conn.Close();
            return new DataSet();
        }
    }
```

How that is with Handler? like if i want to get all these values with Jquree then what i do for that. How i return a dataset from handler.

Comment: we can return dataset like this line of code..

    context.Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["img"]);
or for many rows in one column we do this for the other values

    context.Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["img"]);
    context.Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[2]["img"]);

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use Handler. You can use PageMethod and call it from Jquery using Ajax

Read this http://encosia.com/easily-build-powerful-client-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/